# Always include the latest version of custom Google Drive library

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to link a custom library to a document that will be copied and shared with many people. I want to have all documents link to the latest version of the library, so when I modify the library I don't have to access all the documents to change the link.

This is the scenario:

I created a simple single function library (e.g. library `TestLib`, function `foo()`), and saved a first version of it. Then I've created a SpreadSheet with a script that generates a user menu that calls function `TestLib.foo()`. I've linked version 1 of the library to the script. Now I want to make several copies of the document, one for each people who will need it. The problem is that these documents are linked to version 1 of the library. If I made a change to the library and create a version 2, I have to manually re-link all documents to the new version. That's gonna be lot of work...

Is there a way to have the script to always link to the latest version?

NOTE: the library project is shared in read-only mode (people won't collaborate with the code. They just call `foo()` from the menu when needed).

Thank!

MIX

---

I made a new test, trying to overtake the version "limitation" problem.

The idea is a little complicated, but promising. The spreadsheet calls a function in library LinkLib: this library will be saved in a single version and the source code will never modified. The library function simply calls a function on another library (MainLib), whom source code can change over time. Spreadsheet doesn't need to change the version of the linked library (there will never be new version of BaseLib source code), while BaseLib can change the version of MainLib linked if I made changes in MainLib's source code..

The problem is: changing the version of a linked resource is treated as a source code modification. So you need to save a new version of BaseLib to actually use an updated version of MainLib's function.

Hope this mess is somewhat clear...

It makes sense that the described version management behave like this. But damn, I'm still stuck with this problem...

Answer (score 0):

this is possible but with a risk. simply use "development mode" for all documents using the library. whenever you update the library it will include the new code automatically.

the risks are that you will have to be careful to never save an intermediate/partial change as all changes need to not break anything. this can be tricky and is best to have a separate library copy to use when making and testing changes. once tested you may copy all files and "save all" together so the script doesnt have partial saves.

basically you lose the development facilities of using versions.

read more about [library development mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#testAndDebug) in the official docs.

Comment: There is also the risk that the people I share the library with can edit the code, right?